# Get List of Teams from Graph API now returning Auth Error. Was working 2 weeks ago, what changed?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have built a feature on our project that utilizes the Graph API to retrieve all of the user's joined teams. The last time I know that this feature was working flawlessly was on Nov 3. Now I'm getting the following error when I tried to perform the query:

> Code: AuthenticationError
> Message: Error authenticating with resource.

The query is:

```
            var teams = await _graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

We have other queries that utilize this graphClient and they work just fine, so I don't think there are any issues with my bearer token.

```
var user = await _graphClient.Users[userEmail]
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

var userDetails = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

We're getting close to deployment so I'm getting a bit nervous. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: We still have User.Read.All in our permissions.

Comment: Share the requestid, timestamp along with the error for the above issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

date: 2020-11-18T19:19:08
request-id: 4ebdc0b0-1b6b-4016-a879-a23b37ffd0b8

Comment: The above error is telling that its failing due to authentication. Above i see that you updated it worked earlier and now its not working. Is it from the same device? Check with your administrator whether they enabled any conditional access for the device? If yes, make sure your device adheres to it. So make sure you log-in from a compliant device, provide correct authentication and re-try to make the API call. Share an update how it goes.

Comment: I'm on a personal computer now, and I suppose MSFT does not like my device much. Tested this out on my boss's domain joined virtual machine, and the queries worked! So you're right, with the recent changes that MSFT have rolled out, they no longer think I'm on a compliant machine. Heck, I can't even login to my teams account online anymore without being told that I'm on a non-compliant device. Thanks a lot! I'm going to have to setup a new Dev environment in a virtual machine and go from there.

Comment: Dev, if you put your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @vfirma. Wow, that's a great news. Glad to hear that the resolution helped you moving forward.

Comment: Yes please consider upvoting it. I will move this to answer. So it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The error is not a regular API response/error that returned for the above API call. So its tricky!!
- Above error is telling that its failing due to authentication and it's related to compliant policies related to device, enrolled part of an organization.
- Based on the suggestion, you validated, confirmed that the issue is
  not happening with domain joined machine, but with the personal device which is not enrolled in the domain, nor it has the compliant policies.